# Restrict an XML Schema element to contain a more specific type

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a schema containing the following type, which is designed to essentially hold a list of elements corresponding to game mods:

```
<xs:complexType name="OrderedModTemplateType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        ...
        <xs:element name="Mods" type="mods:ModsType" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:key name="modKey">
                <xs:selector xpath="Mods"/>
                <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
            </xs:key>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    ...
</xs:complexType>
```

The ModsType type, which is what holds the list of mods, looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="ModsType">
 <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="Mod" type="ModType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is the ModType type, which ModsType expects as its children:

```
<xs:complexType name="ModType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        ...
    </xs:sequence>
    ...
    <xs:anyAttribute/>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'd like to create a more specific OrderedModTemplateType, exactly the same as the one posted above, except that the Mod elements within the Mods element would be required to be a more specific derived type of Mod, specifically, Fallout3ModType:

```
<xs:complexType name="Fallout3ModType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="mods:ModType">
            <xs:attribute name="requiresFose" type="xs:integer" default="0" />
            <xs:attribute name="foseVersion" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

So, I know I can use Mod elements of type Fallout3ModType by specifying xsi:type in the element, but what if I want the  element to ONLY contain  elements of type Fallout3ModType, but no less-specific types, such as just ModType (which is the type accepted by default)?

I don't want to have to do this:

```
<Mods>
  <Mod xsi:type="Fallout3ModType" ...>
    ...
  </Mod>
  <Mod xsi:type="Fallout3ModType" ...>
    ...
  </Mod>
</Mods>
```

Can I extend ModsType to Fallout3ModsType, which only accepts Mod elements of Fallout3ModType instead of just ModType? If so, I could then use something like:

```
<Mods xsi:type="Fallout3ModsType">
  <Mod ...>
    ...
  </Mod>
  <Mod ...>
    ...
  </Mod>
</Mods>
```

Or, can I somehow extend OrderedModTemplateType to have a Mods element of type Fallout3ModsType instead of ModsType? In that case, I could use the new type to make usage simpler in XML:

```
<Mods>
  <Mod ...>
    ...
  </Mod>
  <Mod ...>
    ...
  </Mod>
</Mods>
```

I'm really struggling with figuring out if I'm going about this the right way, or if I'm missing something...

**Update**

This seems to validate, but I have a feeling it's not right:

```
<xs:complexType name="Fallout3ModsType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="mods:ModsType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Mod" type="Fallout3ModType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Wouldn't this be essentially defining another, separate Mod element that differs only in type to the original Mod element? If that's legal, how will the parser know which element I am referring to without looking deeper into the nested elements?

Or perhaps did I stumble on the right way to override a type with a more specific type? I doubt it...

**Update 2**
Removed some of the schema info that's irrelevant to the question. It's still a bit long, sorry...

Comment: There is nothing wrong about type extension. About the restrictions for base type, I think you are looking for [abstract element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#abstract)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a substitutionGroup and potentially an abstract element, you should be able to do something like:

```
<Mods>
    <Mod />
    <Fallout3Mod />
    <Mod />
</Mods>
```

Example xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="ModsType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="mods:ModAbstract" maxOccurs="unbounded" ></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ModType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute/>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="Fallout3ModType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="mods:ModType" />
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="ModAbstract" abstract="true" type="mods:ModType" />
<xs:element name="Mod"  type="mods:ModType" substitutionGroup="mods:ModAbstract" ></xs:element>
<xs:element name="Fallout3Mod"  type="mods:Fallout3ModType" substitutionGroup="mods:ModAbstract"></xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful! One additional question then, would it be possible to derive a new type which restricts the sequence to only use a specific substitution group? Or, would it be possible to redefine the Mod element as mods:Fallout3ModType to effectively override the original?

Comment: I think the first question is effectively what is here.  The ModsType can only take items derived from ModAbstract or that are in its substitution group.