# Restrict xsd complex type with more specific element type

Tags: xsd

In essence I want to do this:

```
<xs:complexType name="test1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="test1Value"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="test2">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:test1">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="test2Value"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="refer1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="refer1Value" type="tns:test1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="refer2">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="tns:refer1">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="refer1Value" type="tns:test2"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

In general you can insert a "test2" instance when you define "test1" by adding an xsi:type so it can be resolved properly. However the question is, can I enforce -for a specific subtype refer2- that you must send a test2 type using restrictions?

Whether or not this would still require an xsi:type to be set is a different (though interesting) question.

Note that unlike this previous question ([Restrict an XML Schema element to contain a more specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532635/restrict-an-xml-schema-element-to-contain-a-more-specific-type)) the aim is not to use a custom tag to indicate a more specific subtype which could be achieved with choice or substitution groups but rather use xsi:type to indicate a specific subtype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since test2 is not a restriction of test1, the definition of refer2 does not constitute a restriction of refer1, either in the normal sense of the word 'restriction' or as operationalized by XSD.  So no, you can't do what you want and call it restriction in XSD.